# The day of the month does not show up properly in javascript (html)

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code:

```
function borrowbook ()

{

var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth()+1;
var year = today.getFullYear();

var input_day = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
var newday = today.setDate(day + input_day);

var fulltime1 = newday + "-" + month + "-" + year;

alert ("Return Date is: " + fulltime1);

}
```

And the result was not my expected result:

[image]

Actually what I want to do is if a user enters a value in 'Days allowed',I want to display the book return date.But I do not know why does the day of the month cannot show up properly.Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
var newday = today.setDate(day + input_day);
```

you are setting the value of *newday* to the return value of *today.setDate(...)*, which is a [time clip](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.14).

Since *input_day* is the value of a form control, and such values are always strings, the `+` operator will concatenate the values, not add them.

What you probably want is the date, so:

```
today.setDate(day + +input_day); // set the new date, converting input_date to Number
var newday = today.getDate();   // get the new date
```

Also, you should get the month and year **after** adding the day as it may change their values:

```
31 May + 1 day -> 1 June
```

Comment: *input_day* needed to be converted to a Number, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things you need to change.

Here is a working jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/bbankes/VMn3x/

First, the month and the year may also be incorrect.  If today were 31-Dec 2014, your code would not show 10-Jan 2014, but instead 10-Dec 2013.  You can rectify this by getting the day month and the year from the renew date instead of today's date.

Second, `input_day` is a string, so you need to parse it as an integer using the built-in javascript function `parseInt()`;

Third, the `setDate()` method on a `Date` object does not return the new date.  This is the problem that RobG shows.

The new function is as follows:

```
function borrowbook() {
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var input_day = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

    var returnDate = new Date();
    returnDate.setDate(day + parseInt(input_day));

    var returnDay = returnDate.getDate();
    var returnMonth = returnDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var returnYear = returnDate.getFullYear();

    var fulltime1 = returnDay + "-" + returnMonth + "-" + returnYear;

    alert ("Return Date is: " + fulltime1);
}
```

Comment: The *setDate* method happily accepts a string, the issue is the overloaded `+` operator and string value. +1 for picking up on that.

Comment: It works,thank you very much:)But I have a problem, what is the reason that makes 'input_day' is a string?

Comment: @user3310635– *input_day* is the value of a form control, and they are always strings.

Comment: RobG makes some great clarifications.  Like he said, input_day is the value of a form control, and they are always strings, regardless of the type.  See [http://jsfiddle.net/bbankes/KkEw6/](http://jsfiddle.net/bbankes/KkEw6/) Thanks @RobG